# How to filter columns via MDX

Tags: mdx, olap-cube

Im new (couple of days to be exact) on Cubes, I have the following problem.

I have a Measure that brings certain amount of data, 100 rows for example. From that data I want to filter numbers that are < 0 from one of its columns.

For example this measure:
**[Measures].[Distribution CSU Groups]**

Will bring data like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVnG1.jpg)

As you can see in the link, I want to filter those rows that have negative values on the 3rd column.

Is it possible to do this via MDX and how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes filtering is possible in `mdx` via the following functions:

[`IIF` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145994.aspx)

[`FILTER` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146037.aspx)

[`HAVING` clause](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d4bae7da-5f80-4bee-a5cd-29013a216c6f/having-clause-in-mdx?forum=sqlanalysisservices)